# Making new dataframes from old dataframes by column number

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to re-organize my dataframes by Column orders

for Example

```
x <- data.frame("A" = c(1,1), "B" = c(2,2), "C" = c(3,3))
y <- data.frame("A" = c(2,2), "B" = c(3,3), "C" = c(4,4))
z <- data.frame("A" = c(3,3), "B" = c(4,4), "C" = c(5,5))
```

Say I have dataframes as above.
What I want to do is make new dataframes by column orders of those above dataframes. (Simply put, I want to put all the "A"s ,"B"s and "C"s, to 3 new dataframes.

the below dataframes are my wanted results

```
a <-  data.frame("A" = c(1,1), "A" = c(2,2), "A" = c(3,3))
b <- data.frame("B" = c(2,2), "B" = c(3,3), "B" = c(4,4))
c <- data.frame("C" = c(3,3), "C" = c(4,4), "C" = c(5,5))
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate column names in a dataframe.

Comment: Agreed. I wanted to make a quick example an made that mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(x, y, z) %>% 
     transpose %>%
     map(~ do.call(cbind, .x))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
lapply(names(x), function(nm) cbind(x[, nm], y[, nm], z[, nm]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have equal number of columns in all the dataframes, one way is to use `lapply` over list of dataframes and subset them sequentially.

```
lst1 <- list(x, y, z)
lapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) cbind.data.frame(lapply(lst1, `[`, i)))

#[[1]]
#  A A A
#1 1 2 3
#2 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#  B B B
#1 2 3 4
#2 2 3 4

#[[3]]
#  C C C
#1 3 4 5
#2 3 4 5
```

If your dataframes are not already sorted by names you might want to do that first.

```
lst1 <- lapply(list(x, y, z), function(i) i[order(names(i))])
```

---

We can also use `purrr` using the same logic

```
library(purrr)
map(seq_len(ncol(x)), ~cbind.data.frame(map(lst1, `[`, .)))
```